# How to define two components on the same DOM element

Tags: alpine.js

I am trying to define two components on the same DOM element.
Unfortunately, the following code doesn't work

```html
<div x-data="{ sidebarOneOpen: false; sidebarTwoOpen: true }">
 ...
</div>
```

> Alpine Expression Error: missing } after property list
>
> Expression: "{ sidebarOneOpen: false; sidebarTwoOpen: true }"
>
> cdn.min.js:1:4996

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comma `,` instead of a semicolon `;`

According to Alpine.js documentation it says that:

"`x-data` is evaluated as a normal JavaScript object"

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that.